# nullIV in Crypto.Cipher.Types

Tags: haskell, cryptography

When I run this code using `runhaskell` command

```
import Crypto.Cipher.Types

main::IO()
main = do

    let iv0 = nullIV

    print ""
```

it throws an error

```
• No instance for (BlockCipher c0) arising from a use of ‘nullIV’
• In the expression: nullIV
  In an equation for ‘iv0’: iv0 = nullIV
  In the expression:
    do let iv0 = nullIV
       print ""
   |
14 |     let iv0 = nullIV
```

but when I try in ghci it works

```
Prelude> import Crypto.Cipher.Types
Prelude Crypto.Cipher.Types>     let iv0 = nullIV
Prelude Crypto.Cipher.Types> :t iv0
       iv0 :: BlockCipher c => IV c
Prelude Crypto.Cipher.Types>
```

why it doen't work using `runhaskell` command

Comment: In your ghci, the spacing is different

Comment: spacing is different  means? are you talking about indentation?

Comment: Likely, `c0` is ambiguous: in your code there is nothing which allows GHC to choose a specific cipher, so that it can concretely generate the null IV. In GHCi, relaxed rules make `iv0` polymorphic, deferring the choice of `c`. Try writing your full code, so that `iv0` is actually used by some function, or assign it a specific cipher using a type annotation.